# errors while launching discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**`        throw new DiscordjsRangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
^

```
RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
```

`**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.VoiceStates,

  ],
});
```

**so the** `GatewayIntentBits.VoiceStates,` **is creating error that i placed above code. i don't know why it's creating that error. can anyone help?**

i tried to make music and warning discord bot. and i expected it ://

Answer (score 0):

From [this Discord API Types enum outline](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits), there is a type named GuildVoiceStates instead of VoiceStates. I believe using GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates should resolve.

Comment: thanks. i will try using it. is there any way that i can message you for any help?